# (Failed to resolve , two libararies with same package name) Conflict between gms library and firebase-messaging

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here I want to use two libraries in my gradle files which are not from same package but it doesnt allow me to use it, how can I solve it?

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/fortumo-in-app-android-sdk.jar')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Comment: can you provide the exact error?

Comment: @n.arrow001 i think suffering from `duplicate` issue

Comment: Be sure to use the same version of Play Services libraries. play-services-ads:9.4.0 with firebase-messaging:9.4.0

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

**<s>Conflicting</s>** between two same type **`com.google`** library .

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Call `firebase-messaging:9.4.0` instead of `play-services-ads:7.5.0`

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Gradle** .Before starting work please read **[Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)**

Answer (score 2):

Android force you to use the same google version of dependencies if you are using more then one google dependencies.
So i'll suggest you to use the latest dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

Replace above dependency with the below one and you are good to go.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're getting an error, something like this:

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Which is quite self-explanatory.

Change the following:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks A loooooooooooooot